# Render a page with a single component on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code:

```
<Router>
    <React.Fragment>
        <Link to={`/question/${question.id}`}
              style={{display: 'block', margin: 'auto'}}>Rozwiaz to zadanie kurwo
        </Link>
        <Route path={'/question/:id'} component={Question}/>
    </React.Fragment>
</Router>
```

Right now, when I render the Question component it gets rendered under the li element. Like this:

[image]

[image]

I'd like it to basically rewrite the `<div id="root"></div>` part of the website. How can I do that? It's weird but it does it with the navbar. Code here:

```
<Router>
    <React.Fragment>
        <Bar>
            <Bar.Header>
                <Bar.Brand>
                    <Link id='home' to="/">UczIchApp</Link>
                </Bar.Brand>
            </Bar.Header>
            <Nav>
                <LinkContainer id='about' to='/about'>
                    <NavItem>O nas</NavItem>
                </LinkContainer>
                {
                    this.state.user ?
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <LinkContainer id="questions" to='/questions'>
                                <NavItem>Zadania</NavItem>
                            </LinkContainer>
                            <NavItem onClick={this.logout}>Wyloguj się</NavItem>
                        </React.Fragment>
                        :
                        <NavItem onClick={this.openLogin}>Zaloguj się</NavItem>
                }
            </Nav>
        </Bar>
        <Route exact path="/about" component={About}/>
        <Route exact path="/questions" component={Questions}/>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
    </React.Fragment>
</Router>
```

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I had multiple `Routers` declared. Link to a post that solved it: [React router renders component after a refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50696572/react-router-renders-component-after-a-refresh)